# How to read all table names from Oracle thru Spark

Tags: oracle, apache-spark

I want to fetch table names from Oracle database via Spark.

But it always failed.
with error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> Sql = SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE 1=0, OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM
> sys.tables WHERE 1=0, Error Msg = ORA-00942: table orview does not
> exist

Have I missed something ? thanks.

```
class TrxxConnection(sparkSession:SparkSession) {
  val trxxCon = sparkSession.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//*****:****/****")
    .option("user", "*****")
    .option("password", "*****")
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

  // import sparkSession.implicits._
  // // List the name of all tables in ARAMIS Database
  def AllTableList =
      trxxCon
      .option("dbtable", "information_schema.tables") // or use sys.tables
      .load()
      .select("name").orderBy($"name".asc)
}
```

[image]

```
// below is unit test
println("Begin to establish connection to Oracle")
val AllTableList = new TrxxConnection(sparkSession).AllTableList // Dataset[Row] type
println("Connection to Oracle established")


println("Number of all  tables: " + AllTableList.count())
AllTableList.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there's no such thing as `tables` owned by `sys` available to you (nor me, when we're at it):

```
SQL> select count(*) from sys.tables;
select count(*) from sys.tables
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

What to do? Use something that *is* available to you, e.g. your own tables in `user_tables`:

```
SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        30
```

or tables accessible to you, owned either by you or someone else:

```
SQL> select count(*) from all_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       842

SQL>
```

or, if you are powerful enough, the whole database's tables by querying `dba_tables`:

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from dba_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      2398

SQL>
```

Pick one.

---

As I'm connected as `sys` right now, what do I see in that `tables` thing you used?

```
SQL> select * from tables;
select * from tables
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
```

Still nothing.

So, where exactly did you find information about `tables` owned by `sys` you could use for that query?

Comment: thanks. how to select table names under a specific databse: myDB

such as trxxCon.option("dbtable", "myDB") ?

Comment: What do you call "a specific database"? In Oracle, usually it is just one database which has many **schemas**. If that's what you're looking for, then you have to connect as the owner and read from user_tables. Otherwise, connect as a privileged user (such as SYS, if you don't have any other (you should)) and query dba_tables, filtered by contents of the OWNER column

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Oracle.
I just used your suggestion ==> .option("dbtable", "user_tables")
it worked, although it returned 0 table names.

Comment: I want to fetch the tables names under ARAMIS, as you can see in my screenshot. 
Any changes that I need to adapt in my code ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Spark but - as far as Oracle is concerned - you'd e.g. `select table_name from dba_tables where owner = 'ARAMIS'`. As user_tables shows only your own tables, there's no OWNER column there so - unless you're connected as user named ARAMIS, you won't see its tables.